# Prevent duplication in asp:table on refresh using AJAX timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I've created a very simple bit of code in C# to display data in an asp:Table. On the initial page load all looks great. I've used an AJAX timer to refresh every 15 seconds to keep the data up to date. The problem is after it refreshes the table shows all the data duplicated. I've tried debugging and again all looks good until the AJAX refresh and then it seems to jump all over the place in the C# code rather than following the expected sequence.

Hopefully I've not approached this in completely the wrong way but if I have please tell me! Is there a way to prevent/fix this duplication?

I've replicated the problem code here in a very simple form. Default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="testASPTables._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="15000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

...and the codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace testASPTables
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TableRow[] tRows = new TableRow[5];
            TableCell[] tCells = new TableCell[5];


            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                tRows[i] = new TableRow();
                Table1.Rows.Add(tRows[i]);

                tCells[i] = new TableCell();
                tRows[i].Cells.Add(tCells[i]);

                tCells[i].Text = "Cell Number: " + i.ToString();
            }

        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page_Load(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Page_Load` twice. `Page_Load` runs on postback, then you call it again from `Timer1_Click`.

You need to always be concious of whether the page is in a postback or not and how `Page_Load` works.

Here's what I'd do.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadTableData();
    }
}

protected void LoadTableData()
{
    Table1.Rows.Clear(); //I added this
    TableRow[] tRows = new TableRow[5];
    TableCell[] tCells = new TableCell[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        tRows[i] = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(tRows[i]);
        tCells[i] = new TableCell();
        tRows[i].Cells.Add(tCells[i]);
        tCells[i].Text = "Cell Number: " + i.ToString();
    }
}


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadTableData();
}
```

Oh, and in addition to that, you'd need to clear the existing table rows.

By the way, this is very inefficient. You're reloading the entire table every 15 seconds. Multiple that by a few clients and you're practically performing a [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack on yourself. Consider using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to push new changes to the clients as rows are added to the underlying data.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'll check out SignalR now too, thanks again!